# Android/Java SSL, keystore, certificate reference request

Tags: java, android, ssl, certificate, keystore

I am running into myriad problems with my attempt to connect to a secure server via https in Android (Eclipse is my ide). My lack of understanding re. Java, Android, ssl and certificates is too much for google searches/stackoverflow to yield useful answers. 
     Can anyone point me to a reference (book or otherwise) that spells out connecting to a secure sever, and all that's involved (keystore, certificate, etc), in detail? An Android reference is preferred, but a Java reference is fine. I need to understand the basics of how Java uses https classes, keystores, certificates, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest reading through the Java EE SSL guide, found here: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbxw.html

This should give you about all you can handle for connecting to SSL using Java.

Comment: Thank you! I'm still reading through it all. Am I correctly understanding that to communicate via https with a site that has a thawte certificate (I maintain the site but not the server), that I need to create a keystore, etc., in order to establish a connection? I'd be consuming web services on the server.

Comment: As far as I know, yes - you need to create a keystore with your public key to authenticate with in the store. Then you should be able to use that to create the SSL handshake.